# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: [filename] " while trying to configure twarc2 library for fetching twitter data using Twitter api v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, file-not-found, python-twitter

I am trying to install and configure twarc2 library for getting full archive search from twitter. But while configuring using twarc2 configure , After I enter my Bearer token ,I get the error message. I have attached the screenshot of the error below. Please suggest possible solution to resolve this.

To know more about twarc: [Twarc2 library](https://twarc-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twarc2/)

[image: File not found error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this problem was due to Code to create config file (when not present) was not available in twarc library and thus this issue. This issue had been reported in github and is resolved now.

[Issues-Docnow/twarc - Github](https://github.com/DocNow/twarc/issues/481#event-4884742201)

Solution is just

```
pip install --upgrade twarc
```

It will upgrade to latest version(2.1.7).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just stumbled over this:
https://github.com/DocNow/twarc/releases/tag/v2.1.7

Apparently the was a bug in the code of twarc 2.1.6 which has been fixed in 2.1.7.

I just upgraded with pip an everything worked fine.